# Windows 8 and triggering the display of Windows Virtual Keyboard

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

This is more of a follow-up to the following question asked last year by [ForbesLindesay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272958/forbeslindesay) regarding showing or suppressing the Windows Virtual Keyboard via .NET code:

[How do I trigger or supress the display of Windows Virtual Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871347/how-do-i-trigger-or-supress-the-display-of-windows-virtual-keyboard)

In this case, my application is a WinForms application that *heavily* uses the [Microsoft Ink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms828520.aspx) classes and runs on Windows XP, Vista, 7 and now we're in the process of making sure it works properly with 8.

We've noticed that in windows 8, the Virtual keyboard does not pops up when user wants to use in our application, while it works for normal windows operations.

So - **Now that Windows 8 is out**, is there a way to trigger the Windows Virtual Keyboard in .NET managed code (or [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/) it)?

And if you say there is still no way to do this, can you provide a reference to back up your claim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no way to trigger the Windows Virtual Keyboard in .NET managed code.
You can see that microsoft itself does not trigger the keyboard on it's Desktop application, like file browser:
try to create folder, you should fill the name, but no keyboard is shown.